# SAS merging/condensing data

Tags: sas

I have a dataset similar to the one below

```
ID  A   B  C  D  E
1   1
1          1
1       1
2       1
2             1
3                1
3   1
4          1
5       1
```

I want to condense the data into one row for each ID. So the dataset would look like the one below.

```
ID  A   B  C  D  E
 1  1   1  1 
 2      1     1
 3  1            1
 4         1
 5      1
```

Well I created another table and removed the duplicate ID's. So I have two tables--A and B. I then tried merging the two datasets together. I was playing around with following SAS code.

```
data C; 
     merge A B; 
     by ID;
run;
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried - We're here to help you solve problems with your code, but we won't write it for you

Comment: If you don't post as part of your question what you've tried we can't help you and your question is likely to be deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be solved using the `retain` statement.

```
data B(rename=(A2=A B2=B C2=C D2=D));
  set A;
  by id;
  retain A2 B2 C2 D2;
  if first.id then do;
    A2 = .;
    B2 = .;
    C2 = .;
    D2 = .;
  end;
  if A ne . then A2=A;
  if B ne . then B2=B;
  if C ne . then C2=C;
  if D ne . then D2=D;
  if last.id then output;
  drop A B C D;
run;
```

There are other ways to solve this, but hopefully this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a neat trick I picked up from another forum.  There's no need to split up the original dataset, the first update statement creates the structure and the second updates the values.  The BY statement ensures you only get 1 record per ID.

```
data have;
infile datalines dsd;
input ID  A   B  C  D  E;
datalines;
1,1,,,,,
1,,,1,,,
1,,1,,,,
2,,1,,,,
2,,,,1,,
3,,,,,1,
3,1,,,,,
4,,,1,,,
5,,1,,,
;
run;

data want;
update have (obs=0) have;
by id;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

PROC MEANS is a great tool for something like this.  PROC SQL would also give you a reasonable solution, but MEANS is faster.

```
proc means data=yourdata;
var a b c d e;
class id;
types id; *to avoid the 'overall' row;
output out=yourdata max=; *output the maximum of each var for each ID - use SUM instead if you want more than 1;
run;
```